# django foreign key quotes error

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have two models in two files that import one another. One of them is connected to another by foreign key. To avoid circular import, I am trying to define the foreign key in quotes:

```
from pubscout.models import Campaign
class RuleSuite(models.Model):
    campaign = models.ForeignKey('Campaign', verbose_name="Кампания")
```

this has worked before on other models, but this time I get an error:

```
  ...
  ...
  File "/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/django_cpa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 719, in _check_list_filter_item
    get_fields_from_path(model, field)
  File "/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/django_cpa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py", line 479, in get_fields_from_path
    parent = get_model_from_relation(fields[-1])
  File "/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/django_cpa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py", line 430, in get_model_from_relation
    return field.get_path_info()[-1].to_opts.model
  File "/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/django_cpa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 661, in get_path_info
    opts = self.remote_field.model._meta
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

where should I look to fix it?

Comment: Here is an old answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/4379094/5781248

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to qualify model name with application label:

```
campaign = models.ForeignKey('appname.Campaign', verbose_name="Кампания")
```