# Models not linked after resolving circular import issue

Tags: django

I'm creating an app which allows for users to create reviews of locations. I had an issue with circular imports in Django which I resolved after looking at this post: [Django - Circular model import issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379042/django-circular-model-import-issue)

What I did was get rid of the import in locations.models and do a lazy import of my Review model. In the Django admin, I can create a Review and assign it to a Location. However, when I open that Location in Django admin, it doesn't have any linked reviews.

Haven't found anything so far to suggest why my location is not showing the review that I created. Any help or tips are much appreciated.

Django = 1.9
Python = 2.7

Thanks

locations.models.py:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    ...
    reviews = models.ForeignKey('reviews.Review', null=True, blank=True, related_name="location_reviews")
```

reviews.models.py:

```
from locations.models import Location

class Review(models.Model):
    ...
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: What's your admin code? Maybe the data is there but admin is wrong. Have you checked your database records?

Comment: I havent done any customization of the admin, only registered the models. I have deleted all objects and tried again but no difference. Which db records should I be checking? Using PostgreSQL locally but not that familiar yet with pgadmin

Comment: When I run the shell and import the location and print location.reviews it shows None, so don't think its the admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a foreign key `Review.location`, that means that each review belongs to one location.

```
class Review(models.Model):
    ...
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You can then follow the relationship backwards from a `location` to see its reviews.

```
location.review_set.all()
```

See the docs on [following relationships backwards](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) for more info.

You probably don't need to define a foreign key on both models. Defining a foreign key `Location.review` means that each location has one review (or no reviews), which doesn't really make sense. Setting `review.location` does not update the `reviews` field for that location, they are completely separate fields.

Comment: Thanks, grinning like an idiot after realizing what I was doing wrong. Much appreciated for the help!