# Django import error when trying to migrate models from app to app

Tags: python, django

I am having strange problem with import

I have created new app and trying to move some modules there since some of my apps became really big.

I created new app product added it to my settings file and wrote in product/model.py

```
from django.db import models
from author.decorators import with_author
from item.models import ItemGroup
from item.models import Material

# Create your models here.
@with_author  
class Product(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    itemgroup = models.ForeignKey(ItemGroup, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    material = models.ForeignKey(Material, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    valid_from = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    valid_to = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    style1 = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True, blank=True)
    style2 = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True, blank=True)
    style3 = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True, blank=True)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True, blank=True)
    dimension = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True, blank=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s' % ( self.id, self.code, self.name)
```

when I execute

```
>python manage.py makemigrations item

>python manage.py makemigrations product
```

I am getting an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__ini
__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__ini
__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18
 in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", li
e 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line
198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\src\item\models.py", line 13, in <module>
    from product.models import Product
  File "C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\src\product\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from item.models import ItemGroup
ImportError: cannot import name ItemGroup
```

What could be the problem ?

This is my model of ItemGroup in item

```
@with_author  
class ItemGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, blank=True) 
    #hierarchy = TreeForeignKey(Hierarchy,  blank=True, null=True, related_name='cat') 
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % ( self.id, self.name)
```

Comment: Looks like the issue is because of circular imports. Can you update the post with item/models.py? Would like to know why Product model is imported in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to make cross importing. That is not allowed. Comment out the line 13 in `"C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\src\item\models.py"` if you don't need it.

or comment out the line 3 and 4 in:

```
"C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\src\product\models.py"
```

and do:

```
itemgroup = models.ForeignKey("item.ItemGroup", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
material = models.ForeignKey("item.Material", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm kind of guessing here that you have circular imports going on. Something in `item.models` is trying to import something from `product.models`, which is trying to import something in `item.models`...

The solution to that is avoid it entirely by allowing Django to handle the circular relationship instead of Python, [like in the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379042/django-circular-model-import-issue).

So in your case, remove the import here and instead reference it like a string:

```
@with_author  
class ItemGroup(models.Model):
    # ...
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey('product.SubCategory', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    # ...
```