# Django 1.11: Cannot import name Book

Tags: python, django

I have a problem when I try to import my model "Book" and my model "Comment" from different apps.

My Settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'books',
    'comments',
    ...
]
```

books/models.py

```
from comments.models import Comment

class Book(models.Model):
  owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
  autor = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  description = models.TextField()
  likes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
  created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
  published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
  files = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_location, validators=[validate_file_extension])
  book_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=Book_Type_Choices)
  tags = TaggableManager()
  comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment)
```

and my comments/models.py

```
from books.models import Book

class Comment(models.Model):
  book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name='cooments')
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)
  text = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
  approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I was trying so mamy things but nothing works :(

The error is:

```
  File "C:\Users\a_niu\Desktop\Proyectos\Django\tt\Tescha-books\books\models.py", line 12, in <module>
from comments.models import Comment
  File "C:\Users\a_niu\Desktop\Proyectos\Django\tt\Tescha-books\comments\models.py", line 5, in <module>
from books.models import Book
 ImportError: cannot import name Book
```

Comment: check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187279/python-circular-importing

Comment: and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379042/django-circular-model-import-issue

Comment: Thank u! The second post was the answer, Thank you so much!!

Comment: delete your post please

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265737/6622817 it's actually not recommended to delete duplicate questions