# Django Model ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've been trying to solve a Django circular import problem in my project, using the idea presented in a bunch of answers here on SO, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4379094/6857994)

Instead of something like:

```
from forms_builder.forms.models import Form
#...
Form = models.ForeignKey(Form)
```

This is what I'm doing:

```
Form = models.ForeignKey('forms_builder.forms.Form')
```

The problem is that I'm getting this error:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack

I'm guessing the problem stems from the 2-value **forms_builder.forms**. In the examples I've seen people would only have a 'simple' App name with only one value. (forms_builder is [this app](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-forms-builder) I'm using)

How can I solve this error?

Comment: As far as I remember the foreign key must be related to the Model, not to the Form.

Comment: I don't know how much experience do you have with django, but I suggest you to check [class based views](http://ccbv.co.uk/) and [model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/), they are very useful when you know how to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the app_label `forms` instead of `forms_builder.forms`.

```
Form = models.ForeignKey('forms.Form')
```