# Django count objects field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to create a field that count the number of registered books of each own library.

Each book is related to a library by a ForeighKey

If I register or delete a book it should update automatically in a "book_count" field related to your own library.

libraries/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Libraries(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    book_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

books/models.py

```
from django.db import models

from libraries.models import Libraries

class Books(models.Model):
    library = models.ForeignKey(Libraries, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    book = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.book
```

How can I create this simple book counter in the model of each library?

Comment: I would use the model name Library for most contexts. Also you have a circular import.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - Circular model import issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379042/django-circular-model-import-issue)

Comment: I resolved the circular model problem, but the counter didn't work. I edited the post to make it easier.

Comment: I still see `from books.models import Books`

Comment: Also you didn't have to remove `Books` to resolve the circular import.

Comment: sorry, i'm still starting in Django but i think it has now cleared.

Comment: What is the error message now?

Comment: Now have no error message. But I need know How can I create a field to book count, in the model of each library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it using Signals.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Book)
def add_book_count(instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.library.book_count += 1
        instance.library.save()


@receiver(post_delete, sender=Book)
def rem_statement_count(instance, **kwargs):
    instance.library.book_count -= 1
    instance.library.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the following app

```
$ tree -L 2
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── libraryapp
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py
```

and your models (I've done a small bit of refactoring)

```
$ cat libraryapp/models.py 
from django.db import models

class Library(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    book_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    library = models.ForeignKey(Library, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self):
        super().save()
        self.update_book_count()

    def delete(self):
        super().delete()
        self.update_book_count()

    def update_book_count(self):
        if self.library:
            self.library.book_count = self.library.book_set.count()
            self.library.save()
```

you can get the count of books in a certain library as follows:

```
$ python3 manage.py shell
>>> from libraryapp.models import Book, Library
>>> library = Library.objects.first()
>>> library.book_count
1
```

Note that this assumes the only way to update the book count of a library is through adding or deleting a book.

Comment: I can not do this refactoring. I am already finalizing the project and it would be a very difficult change.

And "book_count" must be in a field of libreries/models.py. It will be register in DB.

Comment: You could make `book_count` a property. See my edit above.

Comment: But you exclude "book_count" field from Library class. Didn't work.

Because I need the IntegerField to be automatically completed/edit by the book count.

Comment: Fair enough. Please see my edit above. Note that I find this less elegant of a design but given how I'm unaware of the rest of the app maybe it is necessary.

Comment: I got it using Signals.

Comment: Nice; you made me realize I was missing the delete side.