# Migration problem in related models with Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

i'm getting some problems migrating my models with Django.
I have 2 models in 2 differents apps:

**authentication model page**

```
import datetime

from consumptions.models import Platform
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from logs.mixins import LogsMixin


class Client(LogsMixin, models.Model):
    """Model definition for Client."""

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cif = models.CharField("CIF", null=False, default="", max_length=50)
    platforms = models.ManyToManyField(Platform, verbose_name=("Plataformas"))
    dateadded = models.DateTimeField("Fecha de inserción", default=datetime.datetime.now)

    class Meta:
        """Meta definition for Client."""

        verbose_name = 'Cliente'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Clientes'

    def __str__(self):
        """Representación de cliente."""

        cif = "Sin empresa"
        if self.cif:
            cif = self.cif

        string = "{} {} ({})".format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name, cif)

        return string
```

And then I have **consumption model page**

```
import datetime

from authentication.models import Client
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now
from logs.mixins import LogsMixin
from rules.models import Rule

class Consumption(LogsMixin, models.Model):
    """Definición del modelo de Consumos"""

    STATES = [
        ('not-prevalidated', 'No prevalidado'),
        ('prevalidated', 'Prevalidado'),
        ('pendant', 'Pendiente validación cliente'),
        ('accepted', 'Aceptado'),
    ]

    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, verbose_name=("Cliente"), null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, verbose_name=("Curso"), null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)

class Platform(LogsMixin, models.Model):
    """Definición del modelo para plataforma"""

    name = models.CharField("Nombre de la plataforma", max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    url = models.CharField("URL de la plataforma", max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
```

As you can see, **from consumptions models I need to import the Platform model for authentication**
And **from authentication models I need to import the Client model for consumptions**

But when I try "makemigrations" I get this

> File "C:\Users\Ángel -
> Trabajo\Documents\AVC\consumptions\models.py", line 3, in 
> from authentication.models import Client   File "C:\Users\Ángel - Trabajo\Documents\AVC\authentication\models.py", line 3, in 
> from consumptions.models import Platform ImportError: cannot import name 'Platform'

I tried to make the migrations app by app commenting certain parts of the code (platform importing, client importing) but in the end I can't get what I want.

As you can see in this image, everything is created in database **but the consumptions_consumption_client table**

[image]

Hope you can help me guys, this is driving me crazy

Comment: probably *circular imports*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I think that is an error related to circular imports

Make sure when you are assigning **models.ForeignKey**  Do not import Model directly instead of doing that use one of the following

1. Use string reference to Link the model as below

```
models.ForeignKey("app_name_where_model_located.Client", verbose_name=("Cliente"), null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
```

2. Use `get_model` method to get Model class

```
from django.apps import apps

Client = apps.get_model("app_name_where_model_located", "Client")
```

Do not directly cross import the models otherwise it may lead to import errors

If you require further help then revert to me

Refer to the following links, They contain the same issue.

[Django - Circular model import issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379042/django-circular-model-import-issue)

https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/