# django circular import in models

Tags: python, django, importerror

I understand I have a circular import here, but one of them is being used to define some foreign key fields and the other is only there for a property in the other model.

models:

receipts/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from employees.models import Employee

class Receipt(models.Model):
    Supervisor = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='receipt_supervisor')
    Employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='receipt_employee')
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```

employees/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from receipts.models import Receipt

class Employee(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    @property
    def receipt_sum(self):
        receipts = Receipt.objects.filter(Employee=self.pk)
        sum = 0
        for receipt in receipts:
            sum += receipt.amount
        return sum
```

I get this error:

**cannot import name 'Employee' from partially initialized module 'employees.models' (most likely due to a circular import)**

Is there a way I can get around this so that I can do the receipt query in the Employee property? Or do I need to do this calculation elsewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: Try importing `Receipt` inside the `def receipt_sum(self):` of the **employee.models.py**  like `def receipt_sum(self):    from receipts.models import Receipt`    ....

Comment: Hi Daniel, have you tried searching for similar questions here? Have a look at this answer, I believe it answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4379094/4744341

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a way I can get around this so that I can do the receipt query in the `Employee` property?

**Yes**, you can import the module in the method:

```
from django.db import models

class Employee(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    @property
    def receipt_sum(self):
        from receipts.models import Receipt
        receipts = Receipt.objects.filter(Employee=self.pk)
        sum = 0
        for receipt in receipts:
            sum += receipt.amount
        return sum
```

but it is actually not necessary to import `Receipt` at all, you can make use of the `receipt_employee` relation to access the related `Receipt` object, and you can use [**`.aggregate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate) to sum up the elements at the database side, this is likely more efficient:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Sum

class Employee(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    @property
    def receipt_sum(self):
        return self.receipt_employee.aggregate(
            total=Sum('amount')
        )['total'] or 0
```

Comment: Oh! Sweet! the import into the property is the way to go. I have some additional math and filtering that I thought would confuse the question, but bonus points to you sir!

Comment: And am just realizing that the relation can have the filter method applied to it `receipts = self.receipt_employee.filter(is_deleted=False, created_at__year=datetime.now().year)` Which is really what I was looking for! Thanks again @WillemVanOnsem