# ImportError: cannot import name 'Item' from partially initialized module 'core.models' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, django

This is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File
   "C:\Users\Abdul\OneDrive\Desktop\django-ecommerce-master\manage.py",
   line 15, in <module> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv) File
   "C:\Users\Abdul\.virtualenvs\django-ecommerce-master-FJQqFcPP\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
   line 446, in execute_from_command_line utility.execute() File
   "C:\Users\Abdul\.virtualenvs\django-ecommerce-master-FJQqFcPP\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
   line 420, in execute django.setup() File
   "C:\Users\Abdul\.virtualenvs\django-ecommerce-master-FJQqFcPP\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py",
   line 24, in setup apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS) File
   "C:\Users\Abdul\.virtualenvs\django-ecommerce-master-FJQqFcPP\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py",
   line 116, in populate app_config.import_models() File
   "C:\Users\Abdul\.virtualenvs\django-ecommerce-master-FJQqFcPP\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py",
   line 269, in import_models self.models_module =
   import_module(models_module_name) File
   "C:\Users\Abdul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py",
   line 126, in import_module return
   _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import File "<frozen
   importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load File "<frozen
   importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked File
   "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked File
   "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in
   _call_with_frames_removed File "C:\Users\Abdul\OneDrive\Desktop\django-ecommerce-master\wishlist\models.py",
   line 3, in <module> from core.models import Item File
   "C:\Users\Abdul\OneDrive\Desktop\django-ecommerce-master\core\models.py",
   line 8, in <module> from location.models import Warehouse, Zone,
   Section, Level File
   "C:\Users\Abdul\OneDrive\Desktop\django-ecommerce-master\location\models.py",
   line 3, in <module> from core.models import Item ImportError: cannot
   import name 'Item' from partially initialized module 'core.models'
   (most likely due to a circular import)
   (C:\Users\Abdul\OneDrive\Desktop\django-ecommerce-master\core\models.py)
```

---

Now, this is being a nuisance. It used to work before but now all of a sudden, it shows me this error. I know what circular imports mean but this used to work before. Now, the 'product' field gives me the problem.

```
from django.db import models
from appsystem.models import Outlet
from core.models import Item, Supplier
from location.models import Warehouse, Zone, Section, Level


class MainPurchases(models.Model):
    METHOD_A = 'CASH'
    METHOD_B = 'CREDIT'

    PAYMENT_METHODS = [
        (METHOD_A, 'CASH'),
        (METHOD_B, 'CREDIT'),
    ]

    product = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    purchase_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    paid_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    outlet = models.ForeignKey(Outlet, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    payment_method = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=PAYMENT_METHODS, default=METHOD_A)
```

Comment: Can you share the full traceback?

Comment: The error simply means you somewhere called or initialised `Item` model in this file and the control goes to that model in core app and from there something (any func, class associated with this file) again called which is in this file, hence circular import.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - Circular model import issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379042/django-circular-model-import-issue) If it makes it any easier the cycle is in between `core.models` and `location.models` as per the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, the problem was in the core app where I used the import statement to import some classes(warehouse,zone,etc).
Removing it resolved it.
Still have no idea why it happened.