# cannot import name '..' from partially initialized module '..models' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: django

**Error while running the program**

> _call_with_frames_removed
>
> File "E:\python\khayyam\khayyam.ir\product\models.py", line 5, in

```
from member.models import Receive
```

> File "E:\python\khayyam\khayyam.ir\member\models.py", line 6, in

```
from product.models import Factor, Product
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Factor' from partially initialized
> module 'product.models' (most likely due to a circular import)
> (E:\python\khayyam\khayyam.ir\product\models.py)

---------------------------product/models.py-----------------------------

```
from levelgroup.models import Sath
from member.models import Receive
from term.models import Term
from user.models import Profile
from django.db.models import Sum

class Product(models.Model):
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='بارکد', default='---')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='نام کالا/خدمات')

class Factor(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='زبان آموز', null=True)
    term = models.ForeignKey(Term, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='ترم', null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='محصول')
    count = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='تعداد', default='1')
    price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='مبلغ')
    discount = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='تخفیف', null=True, default='0')
    maleiat = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='مالیات', null=True, default='0')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='توضیحات', null=True)

def get_pardakhti(self):
    receive = Receive.objects.filter(factor=self.id,         
    student=self.student).aggregate(Sum('price'))
    return receive['price__sum']
```

---------------------------member/models.py-----------------------------

```
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.db.models import Sum
from classes.models import Classes, Grades
from product.models import Factor, Product
from term.models import Term
form user.models import Profile, Branch

class Receive(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='زبان آموز', related_name='receives')
    leson = models.ForeignKey(Classes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='درس', null=True, blank=True)
    factor = models.ForeignKey(Factor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='فاکتور', null=True, blank=True)
    term = models.ForeignKey(Term, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='سال')
```

Comment: You have a circular imports, just as the error message states. Importing a module in Python means executing it from top to bottom. Module attributes don't exists until the part of the code that defines them is run. That means that if you have a module A that imports module B, and module B imports module A and tries to access A.foo, things will explode, since the code that defines `A.foo` won't run until after `import B` finishes.

Comment: Instead of import the models you can use the module string representation, in your case instead of Factor, use `models.ForeignKey("product.Factor", ...)`. 
Take a look at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379042/django-circular-model-import-issue